# Java card applet simulation and debugging

Tags: javacard

I am totally a newbie to Java card platform. Please suggest me a good simulation environment for Java card applets on a Windows based system and if its a GUI based simulation environment it would be a great help.

Answer (score 2):

Please take a look in this http://jcardsim.org/ this is a very good simulation environment for javacard.You can debug in eclipse itself.

Comment: JCardSim is a very bright idea, but beware that it does not completely implement the Java Card runtime environment, e.g. with regard to EEPROM/transient memory.

Comment: Atul please go through the link it is all described there.

Comment: Ok, i'll go through the instructions given.

Answer (score 1):

other possiblity is to debug with JCOP tools which is a plugin for eclipse from NXP. unfortunetly it is not easy to get if you are not working in a company

Comment: Mr. Paul i am a university student hence if there is any other source to easily get JCOP please let me know..